# gnome-power-manager is necessary to spin down hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, gnome-power-manager, sleep

With modern hard disks is necessary to use gnome-power-manager to spin down the hard disks? Or are they prepared to sleep automatically after certain amount of inactivity time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need software like `gnome-power-manager` to spin down hard disks. Modern hard drives sometimes have features like [SMART](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools), but this only collects information. [Psusi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26334/gnome-power-manager-is-necessary-to-spin-down-hard-disks/26345#26345) mentions another great utility, `hdparm`, that plays with power settings (among many other things). Hdparm is more powerful and more advanced, gnome-power-manager is likely easier. More than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 2):

Some ( mostly laptop ) hard disks have such a feature, but not all do.  gnome-power-manager works with all disks.  For disks that support the APM auto standby timer, you can enable it with hdparm -S, or sometimes -B.

Comment: Really? There are disks that will auto-sleep, without any help from the OS or other external programs?

Comment: @djeikyb: yes...